# How to use a list of strings in Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I'm trying to use a list of industries to determine the output text. For example, if the industry is Distribution & Wholesale OR eCommerce OR Manufacturing display some text, else display some other text.

I'm having some issues with the following code:

```
<#if (customer.custentity_esc_industry)=["Distribution \a Wholesale","eCommerce","Manufacturing"]>some text<#else>some other text</#if>
```

However I can't seem to make it work correctly... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<#if ["Distribution \a Wholesale", "eCommerce", "Manufacturing"]
         ?seq_contains(customer.custentity_esc_industry)>
  some text
<#else>
  some other text
</#if>
```

Or even (`?then` requires 2.3.23):

```
${["Distribution \a Wholesale", "eCommerce", "Manufacturing"]
  ?seq_contains(customer.custentity_esc_industry)
  ?then("some text", "some other text")}
```

Comment: Thanks both your solutions addressed my problem. I'm still having trouble with ampersands  for some reason, but everything else is good.

Comment: It works for me with `\a`. But anyway you can write `&` directly. It's not a special character inside FTL string literals.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
<#assign sequence = ["Distribution \a Wholesale","eCommerce","Manufacturing"] />
<#assign flag = 0 />
<#list sequence as seq>
     <#if customer.custentity_esc_industry == seq>
          <#assign flag =1>
          <#break />
     </#if>
</#list>
<#if flag == 1>
     //some text
<#else>
     //some other text
</#if>
```